# Matlab - Pzplot legend

Tags: matlab

I have some troubles to display the legend of each system ... It is only the last system that has a legend... And it seems that is not the correct color ...

[image]

Here is the code :

```
R = 100;
C = 1*10^(-6);

Plant_sec = tf([1],[R*C 1]);
Plant = Plant_sec*Plant_sec*Plant_sec;

for k = [1 3 7 10]
    compensation = tf([k],[1]);
    sys_closed_loop = feedback(compensation*Plant,1);
    pzplot(sys_closed_loop);
    legend(strcat('Gain K =',num2str(k)));
    hold on;
end
legend('show');
```

Thank you for your help :)